# Mathematical notation for a value increase until a certain limit is reached

Tags: notation

How can I say, using mathematical symbols, "**x increases until a certain limit is reached**"?

To give a bit of background info, what I am trying to say is that pressure (**x**) increases in a pipeline system until a first system limit/bottleneck is reached.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the pressure a function depending on other variables? In that case maybe you could say that the derivative is positive and the function itself, bounded. That is, $x'(t)>0$ and $x(t)\le M$ (where $t$ is that other parameter, maybe time, and $M$ the upper bound).

Comment: In set theory, we call such functions "eventually constant", but I'm not aware of a nice notation for these.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x(t)$ be the pressure at time $t$, $f(t)$ be the function that describes *how* $x$ increases before reaching the limit and let $L \in \mathbb R$ be the limit. Then you could write something like

$$x(t) = \min( f(t), L ).$$

For example, if you assume linear growth

$$x(t) = \min(t, L).$$

Now, the function $x$ increases until it hits limit $L$ an then stays there.